# How to Reload the store in Ext js 3.2

Tags: extjs, store, reload

I am unable to load the store outside of `Ext.on-ready(function(){});` using `store.load()` function.I need your opinion and suggestion or you can suggest someone for help? Below is my code,I an using the Ajax function to apply filter to the grid.In show_filter-data_Response(){ function I want to load the function.but not able to load it

```
#Ajax response function
function show_filter-data_Response(response-text, status-text)
{
   #in the response i want to reload the grid
  storefront.load();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to use code blocks. Can you please provide a more complete example?

Comment: @askarkhan : It would be helpfull to you if you provide a sample in either https://fiddle.sencha.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ . So that we can check your mistake and guide you. Or provide almost needed code which you have written for this action.